# Pandas, remove consecutive duplicates of value ONLY

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Current dataframe is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', delimiter=',')

print(df)
idx   uniqueID      String 

0        1           'hello'
1        1           'goodbye'
2        1           'goodbye'
3        1           'happy'
4        2           'hello'
5        2           'hello'
6        2           'hello'
7        3           'goodbye' 
8        3           'hello'
9        3           'hello'
10       3           'hello'
11       3           'hello'
12       3           'hi' 
13       4           'goodbye'
```

Expected Output:

```
idx   uniqueID      String 

0        1           'hello'
1        1           'goodbye'
2        1           'goodbye'
3        1           'happy'
4        2           'hello'
5        2           'hello'
**6        2           'hello'**
7        3           'goodbye' 
8        3           'hello'
9        3           'hello'
**10       3           'hello'**
**11       3           'hello'**
12       3           'hi' 
13       4           'goodbye'
```

*Those in bold should be removed*

Question: **How do I remove the 3rd (or greater) consecutive duplicates of specific value only of the same uniqueID?**

What I've tried to do thus far:

`df = df[(df['String '].shift() != df['String ']) | (df['uniqueID'].shift() != df['uniqueID'])]`

I'm not sure how to get the specific string of 'hello', where it's the 3rd or greater consecutive duplicate. This gets all consecutive duplicates, nonspecific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` base `'uniqueID'` then each group use `shift(1)` and `shift(2)` and check each row with previous and two previous rows and keep rows that are different from previous and two previous rows.

```
msk = df.groupby('uniqueID')['String'].apply(lambda x: ~((x==x.shift()) & (x==x.shift(2)) & (x=="'hello'")))
df = df[msk]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    idx  uniqueID      String
0     0         1     'hello'
1     1         1   'goodbye'
2     2         1   'goodbye'
3     3         1     'happy'
4     4         2     'hello'
5     5         2     'hello'
7     7         3  'goodbye' 
9     9         3     'hello'
12   12         3       'hi' 
13   13         4   'goodbye'
```

Comment: @mozway, thanks, Now work for `A-B-A` case too ;)

Comment: @Ben.T, see edited answer. Is this OK Now?

Comment: It looks like OP's needs :)

Comment: This is close :) . I did not correctly specify in the question I only want this rule to apply where string = 'hello'. So if I've got 3 consecutive 'hello', we only want the first two. But if there are 3 consecutive 'goodbye', then we can ignore that. Is this easy to do?

Comment: @Ev0, yes, you can, you need to add anoter check like : `(x=="'hello'")`. see update.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to get the number of the duplicate and use it for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
N = 3
group = df['String'].ne(df.groupby('uniqueID')['String'].shift()).cumsum()
m = df.groupby(group).cumcount().lt(N-1)

print(df[m])

out = df[m]
```

output:

```
    idx  uniqueID     String
0     0         1    'hello'
1     1         1  'goodbye'
2     2         1  'goodbye'
3     3         1    'happy'
4     4         2    'hello'
5     5         2    'hello'
7     7         3  'goodbye'
8     8         3    'hello'
9     9         3    'hello'
12   12         3       'hi'
13   13         4  'goodbye'
```

If the data is already sorted/grouped by uniqueID, then you can simplify to:

```
N = 3
m = df.groupby(['uniqueID', 'String']).cumcount().lt(N-1)

out = df[m]
```

Comment: @Ben.T I assumed the data is grouped by uniqueID, but you're right, check the update

Comment: Thank you! And yes, the data is grouped prior.